# program to calculate the average of rssi values

Tags: c, decibel

so here i a little code that I need to calculate the average of some rssi values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{

    int8_t rssi_linear_sum;
    int8_t rssi_val;
    int8_t rssi_avg;
    int8_t rssi_num = 0;
    
    int8_t get_rssi(int8_t i)
    {
            return i;
    }
    /* rssi_get() in my actual code is a function that gets rssi 
    values through a bluetooth service, it returns an int8_t value, for the 
    sake of concision, I replaced it with a loop that 
    would return similar values to what I get.*/ 

    for (int8_t i = -100; i <-10; i+=10)
    { 
        rssi_val= get_rssi(i);
        rssi_linear_sum += powf(10, (float)rssi_val / 20);
        rssi_num ++;
    } 
    rssi_avg = 20 * log10f(rssi_linear_sum / rssi_num);

    printf("%d",rssi_avg );
}
```

so I know that to have a precise average to decibel values, you have to linear them first and then get the average. I am just not sure if my code expresses that perfectly. this is more of a logique question rather than a code question, but maybe you can introduce me to a function that does thi or verify that my logique does actually get me the average of values.

Comment: Does your code work well?

Comment: The `get_rssi` replacement code makes no sense. Why not simply skip the loop and just plain `return -100;`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I returns values between -100 and -10 which the range of values I get from the bluetooth service.

Comment: @BeNicePlz, the thing is that this code doesn't actually work. When a function returns inside of a loop, it just returns, once, then it is done. It doesn't yield values like a generator would. You would be better off removing the `get_rssi()` function and just replacing it with the `for (int i=-100; i < -10; i+=10){}` loop from the function.

Comment: @Tim I see what you mean, I fixed the issue. thnx!

Comment: The formula to convert to linear mW should be `pow(10, power_in_dBm/10.0f)`. Where does `/20` come from and why do you do that division in fixed point? Which system is this for?